# ¿Por que no compila?, no me dice el error sale una línea de directorios y ya esta

Tags: java, funciones, compilar

Desarrolla y prueba una aplicación de consola en Java capaz de
buscar los 50 primeros números que existen que sean primos y
capicúas la vez.

> Debe mostrar una secuencia que comienza por: 2,
> 3, 5, 7, 11, 101 y ?
> Debes realizar el programa de manera modular: crea las funciones
> "static boolean esPrimo(int numero)" y "static boolean
> esCapicua(int numero)".
> Realiza tests con JUnit para probar las funciones anteriores del código. Crea varios casos de prueba
> diferentes.

```
public class buscarPrimosCapicuas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    static int darLaVuelta (int numero) {
        String NUMERO = "" + numero; // convierte numero de int a String.
        String RESULTADO = "";
        int posicion = NUMERO.length()-1;
        do {
            RESULTADO += NUMERO.charAt(posicion);
            posicion--;
        } while (posicion >= 0);
        int resultado = Integer.parseInt(RESULTADO);
        return resultado;
    }

    static boolean esCapicua50 (int numero) {
        int contador = 0;
        int buscarCapicua = 0;
        int contadorCapicuas = 1;
        while (contador < 50) {
            if (esCapicua50(buscarCapicua) == true) {
                System.out.println("Este es el número capicúa " + buscarCapicua + " número " + contadorCapicuas);
                contador +=1;
                contadorCapicuas += 1;
            }
            buscarCapicua++;
        }
        int numeroAlReves = darLaVuelta(numero);
        if (numero == numeroAlReves) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int esPrimo(int datos) {
        System.out.println("CÁLCULO DE LOS PRIMEROS 100 NÚMEROS PRIMOS:");
        int cantidadPrimos = 0;
        int numeroCandidato = 2;   // primer número primo
        do {
            boolean esNumPrimo = true;          
            for (int numero = numeroCandidato-1; numero>=2; numero--) {
                if (numeroCandidato % numero == 0) {
                    esNumPrimo = false;
                    break;
                }               
            }
            if (esNumPrimo == true) {
                cantidadPrimos += 1;
                System.out.println(numeroCandidato);
            }
            if (numeroCandidato == datos) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
            numeroCandidato++;
        } while(cantidadPrimos < 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: no te copila por que tu metodo `esPrimo` es de tipo `int` osea debe devolver una variable de tipo `int` y tu estas queriendo devolver valores de tipo `boolean`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar despúes de pasar la función a tipo boleana

Comment: prueba el código cambiando el tipo al metodo sigue sin imprimir los primeros 50 números primos capicúas.

Comment: 1 nunca estas haciendo uso de tus metodos, ya que el `main` esta vacio,un *metodo return* solo te va devolver un valor ,los prints que tienes nunca se van a mostrar a menos que los escribas en el `main` o dentro de un *metodo void* si te sigue marcando error es por que `numeroCandidado++` no se ejecuta por las condicionales que tienes..... revisa el tema de metodos

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código y el compilador reconoce los errores sin problemas. Por ejemplo, el método `esPrimo()` es de tipo `int` pero en las líneas 55 y 58 devuelves valore boleanos (esto me lo mostró el compilador). Así que, en principio, debes cambiar el tipo de dicho método.
Pero si estás usando `javac` adecuadamente ya deberías saber esto.

Comment: Soy estudian de programación y nuestro profesor se fue a un trabajo mejor, estamos en modo autodidacta, el código no es mío es para ETS aprendiendo a usar JUnit y no soy capaz de ejecutarlo a la segunda, al principio me mostraba los primeros 50 primos / capicúas así que estoy reaciendo el código con mí lógica y haré los test en JUnit con ese saludos y gracias por vuestro tiempo (este código funcionaba y cuando fuy a utilizarlos después de editar un println dejo de funcionar).

Comment: Tres comentarios. Java no es un lenguaje amigable para los aprendices. Esta plataforma no está orientada a formar programadores; es un lugar para hacer preguntas específicas que plantean problemas específicos. Antes de lanzarse a tratar de resolver un problema se deben conocer, al menos, los "Fundamentos de programación" del lenguaje en cuestión. Saludos también para ti.